# Powershell command to compare 2 excel tabs

Tags: excel, powershell, tabs

Can anyone pls point me to some example where we can compare contents of 2 excel tabs and writing the result in 3rd tab using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx)

You can get column with that link for compare string you can use

```
$a="soheil"
$b="hidd3n"
$a -eq $b
False
```

Very simple just read link and use object get excel and then compare them with each other